# how to disable password after inheriting AbstractUser to make a custom user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I followed what django docs said about inheriting AbstractUser to make a custom user for easy future changes

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Anyway, I have it now on the admin menu as a different page, it now looks like this [image]

I basically want to disable that input (and others as well). How do I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to *disable some of the model fields in "Django Admin"*?

Comment: not sure you'd call it disable, i remember if i did not inherit the abstractmodel the user edit page would have a noneditable view of the hashed password for the users. but now it's a textbox. not sure why it's the hashed value that's showing up, normally it would be an empty text or just a div with the hashed values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for the [**`readonly_fields`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) and [**`exclude`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) attributes of ModelAdmin,

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('foo', 'bar')
    exclude = ('foo_bar',)
```